# Inverse of a number-valued function on a curve

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, analysis, closed-form

$S=\{(x_1,x_2)\ |\ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\colon x_1=x,x_2=\exp(x)\}$ be a set, and

$f$ be the function $f\colon S\to \mathbb{R},(x1,x2)\mapsto x_1+x_2$.

How can I show if $f$ is bijective?

How can the inverse of $f$ be calculated?

$$$$

I already know that $S\neq\emptyset$, and $S$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Together with dimension invariance theorem follows that $f$ is bijective and has an inverse therefore.

In multivariate analysis, inverses of n-vector-valued n-vector functions are calculated. But it seems we have now a number-valued vector function.

Comment: Isn't $S$ a closed subset of $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: You can write the set more simply as
$$
S = \{(x, \exp(x)) : x\in\mathbb R\}.
$$

Comment: HINT: $f$ is indeed bijective. This follows from bijectiveness of $t \mapsto t+ e^t$. However, its inverse cannot be written in terms of elementary functions (i.e. there is no formula for it). You need to use injectivity and surjectivity (use calculus).

Comment: The inverse of $f$ can be written in terms of the Lambert W function, but this isn't really something you can compute analytically.

Comment: I'm interested in calculating a closed-form expression of the inverse only from the given conditions and the inverses of the component functions. I'm looking for hints why the inverses of bijective number-valued vector functions cannot be calculated on this way. I hope, such hints could lead to a proof someday.